# jQuery, p:parent selector returned one too many element

Tags: jquery

I'm currently studying jQuery API, specifically the `:parent` selector.

Here is my html and jQuery code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="empty-element"><p>
    <p id="with-space"> </p>
    <p id="with-text">hello</p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var $pElementWhoAreThemselvesParentElement = jQuery('p:parent');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My understanding is that `p:parent` select all `p` element who are themselves parent element

I was expecting the `p` element with `id="with-space` and `id="with-text"` to be returned, however, as you can see from the screenshot below, that there is extra `p` element returned by the selector `p:parent`

[image]

I was wondering, why is this happening? Did i do something wrong or was my understanding of `:parent` selector incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you did not close the first `p` tag properly.

```
<p id="empty-element"><p>
```

is missing the **closing tag** which creates a new `p` element in the `DOM`.

Comment: Good catch. Was playing with this and scratching my head a bit and didn't notice the close was missing

Comment: @charlietfl I was doing the same :)

Comment: Thank you very much for helping out @Sushanth-- :)

Comment: A generic comment to the OP (@Thor) is that using `p:not(:empty)` would be a better choice since it would be an official selector and not a jQuery extension.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli thank you very much for the tip. The jquery did mention that its more efficient to use native css selector when possible. Will definitly take your advice on board :)